# How to remove special characters in file names?

Tags: linux, bash

When creating playlists I often came across files that would break the playing process. Such would be files with spaces or apostrophes. I would fix it with the following command

```
for file in *.; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr " " '_'` ; done **(for spaces)**
```

Now I more often come across files with commas, apostrophes, brackets and other characters. How would I modify the command to remove such characters?

Also tried `rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]//' *.mp4` but it doesnt seem to remove spaces or commas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `rename` would work if you add the `g` modifier to it, this performs all substitutions instead of only the first one:

```
$ echo "$file"
foo bar,spam.egg

$ rename -n 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]//' "$file"
foo bar,spam.egg renamed as foobar,spam.egg

$ rename -n 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]//g' "$file"
foo bar,spam.egg renamed as foobarspamegg
```

---

You can do this will `bash` alone, with parameter expansion:

- For removing everything except `a-zA-Z0-9_-` from file names, assuming variable `file` contains the filename, using character class `[:alnum:]` to match all alphabetic characters and digits from current `locale`:

  ```
  "${file//[^[:alnum:]_-]/}"
  ```

  or explicitly, change the `LC_COLLATE` to `C`:

  ```
  "${file//[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/}"
  ```

**Example:**

```
$ file='foo bar,spam.egg'

$ echo "${file//[^[:alnum:]_-]/}"
foobarspamegg
```

Comment: I modified your code a bit and got what I needed except it seems like it left a comma and did not remove it: for file in *.mp4; do mv "$file" `echo "${file//[^[:alnum:]_-.]/}"` ; done

Answer (score 16):

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g'); done &
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifiied the code a bit as well.

As (indir) replacements, say file name purifications, can become complex, I came up with this for the moment:

```
for FILE in *
do
FN=${FILE%.*} # file name without extension
FE=${FILE#$FN.} # extension without dot in front
SUBSTITUTE="s/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g;s/[.]/_/g;s/[ ]/_/g;s/____|___|__|___-___|__-__|_-_|___--___|__--__|_--_/_/g;s/____$|__$|_$//g;s/é|è|ë|ê/e/g;s/à|á|ä|â|ã/a/g;s/ó|ò|ô|õ/o/g;s/ö/oe/g;s/ù|û|ú/u/g;s/ü/ue/g;s/ñ/n/g;s/í|ì|î|ï/i/g;s/ç/c/g"

if [[ "${FE}" != "sh" ]]
then

  if [[ "${FILE}" == "${FN}.${FE}" ]]
  then
  mv "${FILE}" $(echo "${FN}" | sed -r "${SUBSTITUTE}").${FE}
  
  else
  mv "${FILE}" $(echo "${FILE}" | sed -r "${SUBSTITUTE}")
  fi
   
fi
done
```

---

It excludes shell scripts (adaptable).
Consequently it looks for files with and without an extension in a directory.
Most special characters are excluded and accentuated letters replaced by default letters (the German ö is often written as oe, the ü as ue, and there's the Spanish ñ and Portuguese ã etc.).
The thing with the replacement with underscores and hyphens is that you can end up with double, triple underscores and with things like underscorehyphenunderscore which you probably also want to turn into just a single underscore or hyphen.
You talked about mp4 and yes, video files, subtitle files, all those dots in them! Makes it hard for scriptors to easily manipulate.

Oh.do.I.[hate].these.types.off.(x264).files.mp4

Better:

Hm_What_a_Nicely_Convertable_x264_File_I_Have_Here.mp4

It's not perfect, still rudimentary, maybe 'far fetched', needs more testing, but seems to work.

Just don't laugh plz ;)